# mysql trigger function using date add function

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger using the date add function in mysql using phpadmin and getting a syntax error; my goal is to automatically add a date in the estimated finish date column ie 'fin_dt' which is 14 days from the date the order is placed. Ie  current date plus 14 days. I have come up with the following mysql state but get an error:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_orderin BEFORE INSERT ON order_in 
BEGIN 
SET NEW.fin_dt = SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) ;

END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger syntax is wrong. You are missing `for each row` and also you do not need `select` to set the value. It should be as

```
delimiter //
create trigger before_insert_orderin before insert on order_in 
for each row 
begin
  set new.fin_dt = date_add(curdate(),interval 14 day);
end ; //

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Trigger syntax near " SET NEW.fin_dt = SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)"
**SELECT DATE_ADD** is Wrong.  It should be as

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_orderin` 
 BEFORE INSERT ON `order_in`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 SET NEW.fin_dt=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```